# avoid / capture / verify a Javascript alert when testing a method that displays one with qunit

Tags: javascript, alert, qunit, jsunit

I'm just starting using Qunit and would like to know whether is there a way to capture/verify/omit alerts, For example:

```
function to_test() {
   alert("I'm displaying an alert");
   return 42;
 }
```

and then have something like:

```
test("to_test", function() {
  //in this case I'd like to test the alert.
  alerts("I'm displaying an alert", to_test(), "to_test() should display an alert"); 
  equals(42, to_test(), "to_test() should return 42" );  // in this case I'd like to omit the alert
});
```

I'm open to the suggestion of using another unit testing tool as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, looks like [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) is what you are looking for. I've never used it before, but I did to answer your question.

You can replace the global function alert (which is actually window.alert) with a temporary function that will record the message that would have been displayed.

It's easy to do in javascript `(window.alert = function(msg) { savedMsg = msg; })`. So you could do that within your test.

The complexity comes only from cleaning up after you've run your test. That's where you need [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) which can [integrate with QUnit](http://cjohansen.no/en/javascript/using_sinon_js_with_qunit). You'll need [this integration script](http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-qunit-0.8.0.js).

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/git/qunit.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/git/qunit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sinon-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sinon-qunit-0.8.0.js"></script>

<script>

    function to_test() {
      window.alert("I'm displaying an alert");
      return 42;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

      module("Module A");

      test("first skip alert test ", function() {

      var stub = this.stub(window, "alert", function(msg) { return false; } );

      equals(42, to_test(), "to_test() should return 42" );  
      equals(1, stub.callCount, "to_test() should have invoked alert one time");
      equals("I'm displaying an alert",stub.getCall(0).args[0], "to_test() should have displayed an alert" ); 

    });

  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="qunit-header">QUnit example</h1>
 <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
 <div id="qunit-testrunner-toolbar"></div>
 <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
 <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
 <div id="qunit-fixture">test markup, will be hidden</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks memetech! It works awesome, but still i've a little problem, do you know how to make it work for IE 6? It keeps throwing me the "Object doesn't support this property or method" when I do "this.stub..." =(  Thanks!

Comment: I'll keep looking but unfortunately I don't have access to IE6 here to reproduce the issue. Do include the script: http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-ie-1.1.1.js , but I don't think that will solve your issue.

Comment: @Soledad , it is reproducible in IE8+compatibility mode. On line 84 of the sinon.js script, you should add in `&& type != "object"`. IE appears to report built-in functions as type 'object', something Sinon tries to protect against. However, it all works fine. Line 84 should now be: `            if (type != "function" && type != "object") {`

Comment: FYI Christian from sinonjs.org suggests it's not a good idea to remove this protection, and instead you could use `window.alert = sinon.spy()` within your unit test ( I haven't tried it ). You'd have to use `var _savedAlert = window.alert; try { window.alert=sinon.spy(); } finally { window.alert = _savedAlert; }` to make sure window.alert is always restored at the conclusion of the test.

Comment: Memetech, I really appreciate your help. This last solution worked perfectly in IE. Now I'll be able to test my app's whole js logic. Best of luck !